# Frontend & backend integration

Tags: reactjs, laravel, vue.js, express

I understand that the front end should be backend agnostic, meaning a REST API is a REST API.

Speaking to a number of developers for an upcoming project I am continually hearing that if we opt for Vue on the front end then we should use Laravel on the backend however if we use React then Express (Node) will work well.

Why would Vue.js care or even know what the back end was?

My preference is Vue + Express, as I am familiar with Node.js

Comment: Laravel jumped on the Vue train pretty early. Laravel at one point came with Vue by default for a while.  Evan You (creator of Vue) did some Lara-con talks.  The communities are just really close knit.  I would still recommend using whatever backend you're most comfortable with.  I personally use Vue with .NET or Node.js backends.  As you say, frontend being agnostic to the backend, it doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: If you use any kind of SSR then it is much easier to implement in nodejs than in anything else. This is true for both React and Vue. However this also couples your front-end and backend. It's a bit of a complicated topic because you can always consume more than one API if you need to

Answer (score 1):

I think you can see the needs of the program you are going to make, and adjust what technology is good for the program

Answer (score 0):

Front-end frameworks are actually agnostic. Most would recommend you use two frameworks together because of how easy the blend is and how they've built their back-end around a front-end framework. You can keep using your Vue and Express which is not weird at all; I mean it's called a MEVN(MongoDB, Express, Vue.js, Node.js) stack.

Comment: No using Mongo :)